# Run monkey from java

Tags: java, android, bash, shell

I have this script in file script.txt

And I run this like this

```
monkeyrunner /home/user/script.txt
```

this is my script.txt

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
import time

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection("wait forever","emulator-5554")

package = 'com.pak.pak1'

activity = 'com.pak.pak1.MyActivity'

runComponent = package + '/' + activity

#     Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

time.sleep(1)
```

The thing I want to do is to run the script from java

This code runs a shell command for example to srart the script

```
 try {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Process p;
                try {
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("monkeyrunner /home/user/script.txt");

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        System.out.println(line);

                    }
                    br.close();

                    p.waitFor();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    } catch (Exception ie) {

    }
```

And finally mu question is how can I directly from java run the monkey runner commands, I do not want to have the script.txt file. Is this possible ? My goal is to run the monkey runner but I do not want to have the script.txt file

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, if you include the MonkeyRunner chimpchat.jar (and it's jar depedencies) on your classpath, then you can call the monkey runner Java classes directly inside your Java application. Check out [this class](http://source-android.frandroid.com/sdk/monkeyrunner/src/com/android/monkeyrunner/controller/MonkeyController.java) and [this class](http://source-android.frandroid.com/sdk/monkeyrunner/src/com/android/monkeyrunner/controller/MonkeyControllerFrame.java) that make up an example:

[Another thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/rwXy22QBxOs) on this subject

Answer (score 0):

This looks awfully complicated, but still..
monkeyrunner can run interactively, so write directly to stdin (get it from  `p.getOutputStream()`) all strings you want it to run.

you might need to exhaust the stdout before issuing any command, but I don't think that will be the case.